# In Content Security Policy is there a way to match self + any port?

Tags: http-headers, content-security-policy

In development I have a livereload server that runs on the standard port 35729, however this isn't loaded because my because my policy has `script-src 'self'`. Is there way to allow 'self' on all ports?

`'localhost:*'` also isn't a great solution because on occasions I test the site on our local network so it could be an ip address rather than 'localhost'.

Of course I can just remove this header from development if I need to but I am trying to keep it as close to live as possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. `'self'` always restricts you to the site you're in - use it if you're serving your scripts from the same application that your page is in. It's not really intended to allow resources from other processes on the same server.

You can make your sources a config or installation setting. Add `localhost:*` in your development config and change it to the specific `resourceserver:35729` in your LAN testing environment.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think there would be a way but just thought I would double check.

Comment: I've pretty much done what you suggested already I just didn't want to have to change `resourceserver` if my local ip address changes or if I use a different computer. Though now that I think about it I can probably just get the current hostname and then return it with `:35729` appended (in development environment only of course).

Answer (score 19):

Just to clarify - you can use wildcards for the port, but you have to specify the domain. **You cannot use 'self':***

Example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' localhost:* example.com:*" />
```

Mozilla docs:

> The site's address may include an optional leading wildcard (the asterisk character, '*'), and you **may use a wildcard (again, '*') as the port number, indicating that all legal ports are valid for the source**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/default-src#Sources